# How can I nest this Obejct inside another using React/Formik and Yup validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I'm trying to learn how to use Formik and Yup to validate an input(text) form field. I've follwed the standard approach by Jared Palmer and it worked great straight out of the box.

When it comes to doing something a little more component driven, I'm having a tough time achieveing the same level of valdation and I just can't work out where I'm going wrong?

**Yup doesn't seem to be able to identify my Form Model and won't validate the input field as required ...**

I'm thinking that I've actually messed up the Initial Values or I'm not providing them in the right shape that Yup is looking for, but any assitance here would be amazing, this is driving mad...

*I have an example sandbox up and running here > >*

https://codesandbox.io/s/building-multi-step-form-with-formik-yup-vjzpk

**Form Model**
(components/CheckoutPage/FormModel/checkoutFormModel.js):

```
export default {
  formId: "checkoutForm",
  formField: {
    nestedObj: {
      firstName: {
        name: "firstName",
        label: "First name*",
        requiredErrorMsg: "First name is required"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Initial Values**
(components/CheckoutPage/FormModel/initialValues.js):

```
import checkoutFormModel from "./checkoutFormModel";
const {
  formField: {
    nestedObj: { firstName }
  }
} = checkoutFormModel;

export default {
  nestedObj: {
    [firstName.name]: ""
  }
};
```

**Yup Validation Schema**
(components/CheckoutPage/FormModel/validationSchema.js):

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
import checkoutFormModel from "./checkoutFormModel";
const {
  formField: {
    nestedObj: { firstName }
  }
} = checkoutFormModel;

export default [
  Yup.object().shape({
    nestedObj: Yup.object().shape({
      [firstName.name]: Yup.string().required(`${firstName.requiredErrorMsg}`)
    })
  })
];
```

**Address Form which combines Yup and Formik**
(components/CheckoutPage/Forms/AddressForm.js):

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { InputField } from "../../FormFields";

export default function AddressForm(props) {
  const {
    formField: {
      nestedObj: { firstName }
    }
  } = props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <InputField name={firstName.name} label={firstName.label} fullWidth />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens where is that your yup validation will validate an object like

```
{
    nestedObj: {
        [firstName.name]: '' // Validation will get here
    }
}
```

But when you pass to your input `name={firstName.name}` your input is going to be like

```
{
    [firstName.name]: ''
}
```

So you are missing the validation because you added `nestedObj` in the yup validation

OR

You forgot to add `nestedObj` to the `firstName.name`.

So what you can do is change your validation schema to

```
Yup.object().shape({
  [firstName.name]: Yup.string().required(`${firstName.requiredErrorMsg}`)
})
```

OR

Pass to the input, the name `nestedObj`

```
<InputField name={`nestedObj.${firstName.name}`} label={firstName.label} fullWidth />
```

You can pass it as a prop or just hardcode string, you choose.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! You're absolutley right, I was not passing "nestedObj" to Yup, therefore it would not be able to see it. 

Your solution: 
<InputField name={`nestedObj.${firstName.name}`} label={firstName.label} fullWidth />
worked straight away, I can't thank you enough. It was driving me mad, I was too close to the prototype to see the error.